# In this example for a ray intersection with a sphere, where do the underlined values come from?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently revising some things and I came across this solution, however, in the solution it isn't really mentioned how the underlined values were produced, I know how the rest of the values are produced, however, not the underlined ones.

Does anyone know where these values are coming from?

> The vector equation of the ray is
>
> $$r=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\4\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\\-3\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{align}x&=1-t\\y&=-2+2t\\z&=4-3t\end{align}$$
>
> Equation of sphere is
>
> $$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2=16$$
>
> Substituting for $x$, $y$, and $z$ in the equation of the sphere gives
>
> \begin{align}
> &(-t)^2+(-3+2t)^2+(3-3t)^2-16=0\\[0.6ex]
> \implies &t^2+9\,\color{blue}{\underline{-12t}}+4t^2+9\,\color{blue}{\underline{-18t}}+9t^2-16=0\\[0.6ex]
> \implies &14t^2-30t+2=0\\[0.6ex]
> \implies &7t^2-15t+1=0
> \end{align}

Comment: Um, $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: @PM2Ring Could you please convert your comment into an answer so this question doesn't sit in the "Unanswered" queue for another year?

Comment: @PM2Ring Wonderful -- upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

The underlined terms are the middle terms from two squares of sums.

For all $a, b$,
$$(a\pm b)^2=a^2\pm 2ab + b^2$$
Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
&(-3+2t)^2\\
&=(-3)^2+2\cdot-3\cdot2t+(2t)^2\\
&=9-12t+4t^2\\
\\
&(3-3t)^2\\
&=3^2+2\cdot3\cdot-3t+(-3t)^2\\
&=9-18t+9t^2\\
\end{align}$$